# Ie11 Grid collapses on itself

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11, css-grid

I'm trying to use CSS Grid in IE11. From what I've heard, it is posible. What I am trying to do is something like this:

[image]

[Example on CodePen](https://codepen.io/team/gadventures/pen/NozmZp)

My HTML is simple:

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="col">1</div>
  <div class="col">2</div>
  <div class="col">3</div>
  <div class="col">4</div>
</div>
```

The CSS is

```
.grid {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: 1fr 20px 1fr 20px 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.col {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ddd;
}
```

When I load the page in chrome, it's fine (see image above). Alas, here's how it looks in IE11.

[image: IE11]

Even though I've added in the relevant MS prefixes, it still seems like the boxes are stacked on top of each other.

Anyone know what I'm missing here?

Comment: I found this interesting:  https://medium.com/@elad/supporting-css-grid-in-internet-explorer-b38669e75d66
"Grid-gap isn’t supported, but you can use CSS margin instead.
    Grid-template-areas isn't supported, but we can convert it to work with grid lines.
    Important: the HTML <main> tag doesn’t work with CSS grid. Replace it with <section role=”main”>."